# Complex limit question

Tags: limits

> 1. Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2e^{-4x}+xe^{-3x}}{e^{-2x}+xe^{-3x}}$.
> 2. Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2e^{x^4}-\sin{(x^2)}}{1-\cos{(x^3)}}$.

For the first question I got \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2e^{-4x}+xe^{-3x}}{e^{-2x}+xe^{-3x}} &= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{xe^{-3x}\left(xe^{-x}+1\right)}{e^{-2x}\left(xe^{-x}+1\right)} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{xe^{-3x}}{e^{-2x}} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{e^x}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
This has an indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. So we can use L'Hopital's rule to get $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{e^x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{e^x} = 0$.

For the second question I tried L'Hopital's rule but that didn't work and I also tried multiplying by the conjugate $\left(1+\cos{(x^3)}\right)$. Any help would be great!!!

Comment: For the 2nd Q use $1-\cos A=2(\sin A/2)^2 ,$ which is obtained from $\cos A= 2(\cos A/2)^2-1=2(1-(\sin A/2)^2)-1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $0$, you have\begin{align}x^2e^{x^4}-\sin(x^2)&=x^2\left(1+x^4+\frac{x^8}{2!}+\cdots\right)-\left(x^2-\frac{x^6}6+\cdots\right)\\&=\frac76x^6+O(x^7)\end{align}and$$1-\cos(x^3)=\frac{x^6}2+O(x^7)$$and therefore$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2e^{x^4}-\sin(x^2)}{1-\cos(x^3)}=\frac{7/6}{1/2}=\frac73.$$

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't think to use a series expansion!!!

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, how were you able to obtain $O(x^7)$. That has got me thinking for quite a number of times.

Comment: If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is a power series and $N\in\mathbb N$, then$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{N-1}x^{N-1}+O(x^N).$$